# ¿Como puedo agregarle esta otra propiedad a mi consulta SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

En ASP.NET WEB estoy haciendo un filtrado de busqueda para una tabla dependiendo de los items eliga en 2 dropdownlist distintos. Por ahora ya logre que funcione con uno.

```
SQLTable = "SELECT * FROM Mitabla";
SQLTable += "WHERE ID='" + Dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Value + "'";
```

¿Como le agrego esta otra propiedad del segundo Dropdownlist?:

> Dropdownlist2.SelectedItem.Value

Mi objetivo final es que filtre los resultados en la tabla si selecciono ambos.

Ayúdenme a solucionarlo!

Comment: Quieres que filtr por la misma propiedad ID ? , 
O por otro campo... seria que se cumplan ambas condiciones .. o que se sumpla una u otra.

Comment: Exactamente por el mismo campo. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo dejar un espacio en las consultas al comenzar cada linea.-

```
SQLTable = " SELECT * FROM Mitabla ";
SQLTable += " WHERE ID='" + Dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Value + "'";
```

Que se cumplan ambas (AND)

```
SQLTable += " AND PROPIEDAD ='" + Dropdownlist2.SelectedItem.Value + "'";
```

Que se cumpla una u otra(OR)

```
    SQLTable += " OR PROPIEDAD ='" + Dropdownlist2.SelectedItem.Value + "'";
// Si este es el caso recomiendo usar IN
    SQLTable = " SELECT * FROM Mitabla ";
    SQLTable += " WHERE ID IN('" + Dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Value 
     + "'," +  Dropdownlist2.SelectedItem.Value + "')";
```